# On an Android phone, is it safe to assume that the gallery folder will be located in DCIM?

Tags: android, gallery, android-gallery

I'm using Unity, and I'm trying to save a screenshot to the gallery instead of `persistentDatapath`, and so I don't have access to the native Android functions.

Will all Android phones have their gallery in the `DCIM` folder? Either `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/` or `storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/`? Or does it change from phone to phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is the same everywhere and it doesn't change from phone to phone